# WampServer & XAMPPserver automatically redirecting http to https (I don't want this)

Tags: https, wampserver

Every `http` site in my newly installed WampServer 3.1.0 64-bit is automatically redirecting simple `index.html` files with no `.htaccess` to the `https` version of the site.

I can see no `.htaccess` file in `C:\wamp64\www` or `C:\wamp64\www\example`.

If I uninstall WampServer, and install XAMPPserver, the same thing occurs.

Help appreciated.

`httpd-vhosts.conf:`

```
<VirtualHost www.superiorit.dev:80>
    ServerAdmin steve.doig@superiorit.com.au
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/superiorit"
    ServerName www.superiorit.dev
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

`httpd-ssl.conf:` is the standard default file.

The only change I have made to `httpd.conf` is:

```
Listen 172.18.1.106:80
```

I noticed the Chrome icon in the Windows task bar looks different to the normal Chrome icon: [image]

If I load the site in Edge, the redirection does not occur.

Comment: Sorry to ask the obvious but you have got show hidden files enabled?.

Comment: Yes I do thanks @DaveCarruthers.

Comment: Please show us your `httpd-vhosts.conf` file and your `httpd-ssl.conf` file and any amendments you made to your `httpd.conf` file. If there are errors in the `httpd-vhosts.conf` file Apache will fallback to the first vhost defeined in the `httpd-vhosts.conf` file

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly, I've added those details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within a Virtual Host definition you also need tell Apache it is allowed to access the directories that hold the site code i.e. a `<Directory>`

I also learned recently that Google owns the `.dev` tLD so you should consider using something else instead, specially if you are using Chrome browser as google could add anything in there to pick up the use of `.dev` and, well, do anything.

***I now find out that as of V63 Chrome does in fact force a redirection of `.dev`***

***This will also be happening to FF and other browsers***

You also dont need to specify the domain name on the `<VirtualHost www.superiorit.dev:80>` line. The `*` is fine.

So try this an see if things improve.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName superiorit.local
    ServerAlias www.superiorit.local
    DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/superiorit
    <Directory  "C:/xampp/htdocs/superiorit/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog "logs/superiorit.local-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/superiorit.local-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

> Also have a look at [Why all *.dev domains target to my localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28199785/why-all-dev-domains-target-to-my-localhost)

> AND https://tech.slashdot.org/story/17/09/18/192227/chrome-to-force-domains-ending-with-dev-and-foo-to-https-via-preloaded-hsts

Comment: @RiggsFolly  This issue is also coming with latest firefox versions. So please update your answer accordingly.

Comment: @user3733831 Thanks for the info, do you know the version number of FF where this change will happen?

Comment: I am using `59.0.1 (64-bit)`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is your .dev URLs, like RiggsFolly suggested. Thats why it works in other browsers like Edge. This is a new feature coming with Chrome 63. See articles below:

https://superuser.com/questions/1276048/starting-with-chrome-63-urls-containing-app-redirects-to-https
https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/