# Can access localhost but virtual host can't be reached

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, wamp

First post on stackoverflow, so thanks in advance for the help.

I am having an issue connecting to my virtual host (created in WAMP), though I can access my localhost site with no issue.  When I type in my virtual host with .dev extension, I get the following message from Chrome: This site can’t be reached websiteone.dev refused to connect.  Trying to access the virtual host directly through WAMP also fails.  However, all-the-while my localhost domain is working splendidly.

Furthermore, this issue is occurring while setting up a virtual host on my personal laptop using the exact same method as my desktop, which worked perfectly.  I have uninstalled and re-installed WAMP, which has not solved the issue.

More information about my files and OS below:

Laptop: Windows 8.1

Desktop: Windows 10

Software: WAMP, Wordpress

Antivirus: Webroot (have allowed access to hosts file)

hosts file (note that after uninstalling and installing WAMP, the virtual host creation process did not add the host & IP below.  I manually added what you see un-commented below.)

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
127.0.0.1       websiteone.dev
127.0.0.1       websitetwo.dev
```

httpd.conf Apache file (both lines un-commented)

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
```

httpd-vhosts.conf Apache file:

```
<VirtualHost *:8079>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8079>
    ServerName websiteone.dev
    DocumentRoot "c:/users/idupont/documents/my web projects/siteone"
    <Directory  "c:/users/idupont/documents/my web projects/siteone/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:8079>
    ServerName websitetwo.dev
    DocumentRoot "c:/users/idupont/documents/my web projects/sitetwo"
    <Directory  "c:/users/idupont/documents/my web projects/sitetwo/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Apache access log

```
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:48:12 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5646
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:49:38 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5653
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:49:49 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5653
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:49:49 -0600] "GET /wampthemes/classic/style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 2466
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:49:50 -0600] "GET /index.php?img=gifLogo HTTP/1.1" 200 4549
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:49:50 -0600] "GET /index.php?img=pngPlugin HTTP/1.1" 200 548
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:49:50 -0600] "GET /index.php?img=pngWrench HTTP/1.1" 200 741
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:49:50 -0600] "GET /index.php?img=pngFolderGo HTTP/1.1" 200 694
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:49:50 -0600] "GET /index.php?img=favicon HTTP/1.1" 200 1429
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:51:27 -0600] "GET /phpmyadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3299
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:51:27 -0600] "GET /phpmyadmin/themes/pmahomme/jquery/jquery-ui.css HTTP/1.1" 200 36566
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:51:27 -0600] "GET /phpmyadmin/js/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css?v=4.7.4 HTTP/1.1" 200 8132
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:51:27 -0600] "GET /phpmyadmin/js/codemirror/addon/hint/show-hint.css?v=4.7.4 HTTP/1.1" 200 623
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:51:27 -0600] "GET /phpmyadmin/js/codemirror/addon/lint/lint.css?v=4.7.4 HTTP/1.1" 200 2999
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:51:27 -0600] "GET /phpmyadmin/js/get_scripts.js.php?scripts%5B%5D=jquery/jquery.min.js&scripts%5B%5D=jquery/jquery-migrate-3.0.0.js&scripts%5B%5D=sprintf.js&scripts%5B%5D=ajax.js&scripts%5B%5D=keyhandler.js&scripts%5B%5D=jquery/jquery-ui.min.js&scripts%5B%5D=jquery/jquery.cookie.js&scripts%5B%5D=jquery/jquery.mousewheel.js&scripts%5B%5D=jquery/jquery.event.drag-2.2.js&scripts%5B%5D=jquery/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js&v=4.7.4 HTTP/1.1" 200 138812
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:51:27 -0600] "GET /phpmyadmin/js/get_scripts.js.php?scripts%5B%5D=navigation.js&scripts%5B%5D=indexes.js&scripts%5B%5D=common.js&scripts%5B%5D=page_settings.js&scripts%5B%5D=shortcuts_handler.js&scripts%5B%5D=codemirror/lib/codemirror.js&scripts%5B%5D=codemirror/mode/sql/sql.js&scripts%5B%5D=codemirror/addon/runmode/runmode.js&scripts%5B%5D=codemirror/addon/hint/show-hint.js&scripts%5B%5D=codemirror/addon/hint/sql-hint.js&v=4.7.4 HTTP/1.1" 200 135447
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:51:27 -0600] "GET /phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin.css.php?nocache=4510858662ltr&server=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 20142
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:51:27 -0600] "GET /phpmyadmin/js/get_scripts.js.php?scripts%5B%5D=jquery/jquery.ba-hashchange-1.3.js&scripts%5B%5D=jquery/jquery.debounce-1.0.5.js&scripts%5B%5D=menu-resizer.js&scripts%5B%5D=cross_framing_protection.js&scripts%5B%5D=rte.js&scripts%5B%5D=tracekit/tracekit.js&scripts%5B%5D=error_report.js&scripts%5B%5D=config.js&scripts%5B%5D=doclinks.js&scripts%5B%5D=functions.js&v=4.7.4 HTTP/1.1" 200 76958
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:51:27 -0600] "GET /phpmyadmin/js/get_scripts.js.php?scripts%5B%5D=codemirror/addon/lint/lint.js&scripts%5B%5D=codemirror/addon/lint/sql-lint.js&scripts%5B%5D=console.js&v=4.7.4 HTTP/1.1" 200 13176
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:51:27 -0600] "GET /phpmyadmin/js/whitelist.php?v=4.7.4 HTTP/1.1" 200 475
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:51:28 -0600] "GET /phpmyadmin/js/get_image.js.php?theme=pmahomme&v=4.7.4 HTTP/1.1" 200 1841
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:51:28 -0600] "GET /phpmyadmin/themes/pmahomme/img/logo_right.png HTTP/1.1" 200 4601
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:51:28 -0600] "GET /phpmyadmin/themes/dot.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 43
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:51:28 -0600] "GET /phpmyadmin/themes/pmahomme/css/printview.css?v=4.7.4 HTTP/1.1" 200 2746
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:51:27 -0600] "GET /phpmyadmin/js/messages.php?v=4.7.4 HTTP/1.1" 200 8648
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:51:28 -0600] "GET /phpmyadmin/themes/pmahomme/img/sprites.png?v=4.7.4 HTTP/1.1" 200 15764
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:51:28 -0600] "GET /phpmyadmin/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 22486
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:51:30 -0600] "POST /phpmyadmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 302 25
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:51:30 -0600] "GET /phpmyadmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 13326
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:51:31 -0600] "GET /phpmyadmin/themes/pmahomme/img/logo_left.png HTTP/1.1" 200 2827
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:51:31 -0600] "GET /phpmyadmin/themes/pmahomme/img/ajax_clock_small.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 1810
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:51:31 -0600] "GET /phpmyadmin/themes/pmahomme/img/s_collapseall.png HTTP/1.1" 200 170
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:51:31 -0600] "GET /phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin.css.php?nocache=6024244152ltr&server=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 20142
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:51:31 -0600] "GET /phpmyadmin/themes/pmahomme/img/left_nav_bg.png HTTP/1.1" 200 257
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:51:31 -0600] "POST /phpmyadmin/navigation.php?ajax_request=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 2005
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:51:31 -0600] "POST /phpmyadmin/version_check.php HTTP/1.1" 200 28
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:51:32 -0600] "GET /phpmyadmin/server_databases.php?db=&ajax_request=true&ajax_page_request=true&_nocache=1513385492732100852 HTTP/1.1" 200 5907
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:51:35 -0600] "GET /phpmyadmin/themes/pmahomme/img/arrow_ltr.png HTTP/1.1" 200 139
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:51:35 -0600] "GET /phpmyadmin/js/get_scripts.js.php?scripts%5B%5D=server_databases.js&call_done=1&v=4.7.4&call_done=1&v=4.7.4 HTTP/1.1" 200 2154
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:51:41 -0600] "POST /phpmyadmin/server_databases.php HTTP/1.1" 200 1735
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:51:41 -0600] "POST /phpmyadmin/navigation.php?ajax_request=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 2032
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:51:41 -0600] "GET /phpmyadmin/db_structure.php?db=mysite&db=mysite&ajax_request=true&ajax_page_request=true&_nocache=1513385501221324621 HTTP/1.1" 200 2706
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:51:41 -0600] "GET /phpmyadmin/navigation.php?ajax_request=1&aPath=cm9vdA%3D%3D.bXlzaXRl&vPath=cm9vdA%3D%3D.bXlzaXRl&pos=0&pos2_name=&pos2_value=&searchClause=&searchClause2=&_nocache=1513385501532300838 HTTP/1.1" 200 1398
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:51:41 -0600] "GET /phpmyadmin/js/get_scripts.js.php?scripts%5B%5D=db_structure.js&scripts%5B%5D=tbl_change.js&call_done=1&v=4.7.4&call_done=1&v=4.7.4 HTTP/1.1" 200 10875
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:51:47 -0600] "GET /mysite HTTP/1.1" 301 324
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:51:47 -0600] "GET /mysite/ HTTP/1.1" 302 -
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:51:48 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-includes/css/buttons.min.css?ver=4.9.1 HTTP/1.1" 200 6144
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:51:48 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-admin/css/install.min.css?ver=4.9.1 HTTP/1.1" 200 5650
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:51:47 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-admin/setup-config.php HTTP/1.1" 200 11061
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:51:48 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4 HTTP/1.1" 200 97184
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:51:48 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1 HTTP/1.1" 200 10056
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:51:48 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-admin/js/language-chooser.min.js?ver=4.9.1 HTTP/1.1" 200 374
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:51:48 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-admin/images/wordpress-logo.svg?ver=20131107 HTTP/1.1" 200 1521
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:51:49 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-admin/images/spinner.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 4162
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:51:49 -0600] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 202575
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:51:51 -0600] "POST /mysite/wp-admin/setup-config.php?step=0 HTTP/1.1" 200 2346
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:51:51 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-includes/css/buttons.min.css?ver=4.9.1 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:51:51 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-admin/css/install.min.css?ver=4.9.1 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:51:51 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:51:51 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:51:51 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-admin/js/language-chooser.min.js?ver=4.9.1 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:51:51 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-admin/images/wordpress-logo.svg?ver=20131107 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:51:55 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-admin/setup-config.php?step=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 2731
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:51:55 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-includes/css/buttons.min.css?ver=4.9.1 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:51:55 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-admin/css/install.min.css?ver=4.9.1 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:51:55 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:51:55 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:51:55 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-admin/js/language-chooser.min.js?ver=4.9.1 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:51:55 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-admin/images/wordpress-logo.svg?ver=20131107 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:52:14 -0600] "POST /mysite/wp-admin/setup-config.php?step=2 HTTP/1.1" 500 3592
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:53:59 -0600] "POST /mysite/wp-admin/setup-config.php?step=2 HTTP/1.1" 200 1453
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:53:59 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-includes/css/buttons.min.css?ver=4.9.1 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:53:59 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-admin/css/install.min.css?ver=4.9.1 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:53:59 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:53:59 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:53:59 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-admin/js/language-chooser.min.js?ver=4.9.1 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:54:00 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-admin/images/wordpress-logo.svg?ver=20131107 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:54:02 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-admin/install.php?language=en_US HTTP/1.1" 200 6043
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:54:02 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-includes/css/dashicons.min.css?ver=4.9.1 HTTP/1.1" 200 46360
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:54:02 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-includes/js/zxcvbn-async.min.js?ver=1.0 HTTP/1.1" 200 324
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:54:02 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-admin/js/password-strength-meter.min.js?ver=4.9.1 HTTP/1.1" 200 784
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:54:02 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-admin/js/user-profile.min.js?ver=4.9.1 HTTP/1.1" 200 6359
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:54:02 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-includes/js/underscore.min.js?ver=1.8.3 HTTP/1.1" 200 16410
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:54:02 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-includes/js/wp-util.min.js?ver=4.9.1 HTTP/1.1" 200 1046
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:54:03 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-includes/js/zxcvbn.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 822202
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:54:57 -0600] "GET /mysite/2017/12/16/hello-world/ HTTP/1.1" 200 57752
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:54:55 -0600] "POST /mysite/wp-admin/install.php?step=2 HTTP/1.1" 200 3176
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:54:58 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-includes/css/buttons.min.css?ver=4.9.1 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:54:58 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-admin/css/install.min.css?ver=4.9.1 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:54:58 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:54:58 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-includes/js/wp-util.min.js?ver=4.9.1 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:54:58 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-includes/css/dashicons.min.css?ver=4.9.1 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:54:58 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:54:58 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-includes/js/zxcvbn-async.min.js?ver=1.0 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:54:58 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-admin/js/user-profile.min.js?ver=4.9.1 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:54:58 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-admin/js/password-strength-meter.min.js?ver=4.9.1 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:54:58 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-includes/js/underscore.min.js?ver=1.8.3 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:54:59 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-admin/images/wordpress-logo.svg?ver=20131107 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:54:59 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-includes/js/zxcvbn.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:55:02 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 2287
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:55:03 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-admin/load-styles.php?c=0&dir=ltr&load%5B%5D=dashicons,buttons,forms,l10n,login&ver=4.9.1 HTTP/1.1" 200 98104
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:55:02 -0600] "POST /mysite/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1513385702.6940279006958007812500 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:55:09 -0600] "GET /phpmyadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 13354
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:55:10 -0600] "POST /phpmyadmin/navigation.php?ajax_request=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 2032
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:55:10 -0600] "POST /phpmyadmin/version_check.php HTTP/1.1" 200 28
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:55:12 -0600] "GET /phpmyadmin/server_databases.php?db=&ajax_request=true&ajax_page_request=true&_nocache=1513385712225910938 HTTP/1.1" 200 5973
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:55:14 -0600] "GET /phpmyadmin/db_structure.php?db=&db=mysite&ajax_request=true&ajax_page_request=true&_nocache=1513385714208290136 HTTP/1.1" 200 6653
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:55:14 -0600] "GET /phpmyadmin/navigation.php?ajax_request=1&aPath=cm9vdA%3D%3D.bXlzaXRl&vPath=cm9vdA%3D%3D.bXlzaXRl&pos=0&pos2_name=&pos2_value=&searchClause=&searchClause2=&_nocache=1513385714581348812 HTTP/1.1" 200 2081
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:55:23 -0600] "POST /mysite/wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:55:24 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-includes/js/thickbox/thickbox.css?ver=4.9.1 HTTP/1.1" 200 2658
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:55:24 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5B%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=4.9.1 HTTP/1.1" 200 109068
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:55:24 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-admin/load-styles.php?c=0&dir=ltr&load%5B%5D=dashicons,admin-bar,common,forms,admin-menu,dashboard,list-tables,edit,revisions,media,themes,about,nav-menus,wp-pointer,widgets&load%5B%5D=,site-icon,l10n,buttons,wp-auth-check&ver=4.9.1 HTTP/1.1" 200 331399
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:55:23 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 55152
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:55:24 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-includes/css/editor.min.css?ver=4.9.1 HTTP/1.1" 200 25769
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:55:24 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-includes/js/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=4.9.1 HTTP/1.1" 200 11915
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:55:24 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5B%5D=hoverIntent,common,admin-bar,wp-ajax-response,jquery-color,wp-lists,quicktags,jquery-query,admin-comments,jquery-ui-core,jquery-&load%5B%5D=ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-sortable,postbox,underscore,wp-util,wp-a11y,dashboard,thickbox,plugin-install,updates,shortc&load%5B%5D=ode,media-upload,svg-painter,heartbeat,wp-auth-check,wplink,jquery-ui-position,jquery-ui-menu,jquery-ui-autocomplete&ver=4.9.1 HTTP/1.1" 200 244317
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:55:25 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-includes/js/thickbox/loadingAnimation.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 15238
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:55:25 -0600] "POST /mysite/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1513385725.5127670764923095703125 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:55:25 -0600] "POST /mysite/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.1" 200 60
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:55:25 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=wp-compression-test&test=1&_ajax_nonce=d33cdbad70&1513385725035 HTTP/1.1" 200 1114
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:55:25 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=wp-compression-test&test=2&_ajax_nonce=d33cdbad70&1513385725982 HTTP/1.1" 200 572
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:55:26 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=wp-compression-test&test=yes&_ajax_nonce=d33cdbad70&1513385726354 HTTP/1.1" 200 1
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:55:25 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=dashboard-widgets&widget=dashboard_primary&pagenow=dashboard HTTP/1.1" 200 805
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:56:33 -0600] "GET /phpmyadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 13354
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:56:34 -0600] "POST /phpmyadmin/navigation.php?ajax_request=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 2032
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:56:34 -0600] "POST /phpmyadmin/version_check.php HTTP/1.1" 200 28
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:56:41 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5616
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:56:41 -0600] "GET /index.php?img=gifLogo HTTP/1.1" 200 4549
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:56:41 -0600] "GET /index.php?img=pngPlugin HTTP/1.1" 200 548
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:56:41 -0600] "GET /index.php?img=pngWrench HTTP/1.1" 200 741
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:56:41 -0600] "GET /index.php?img=pngFolder HTTP/1.1" 200 850
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:56:41 -0600] "GET /index.php?img=pngFolderGo HTTP/1.1" 200 694
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:56:43 -0600] "GET /add_vhost.php?lang=english HTTP/1.1" 200 4720
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:56:43 -0600] "GET /index.php?img=gifLogo HTTP/1.1" 200 4549
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:56:43 -0600] "GET /index.php?img=pngWrench HTTP/1.1" 200 741
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:57:59 -0600] "POST /add_vhost.php?lang=english HTTP/1.1" 200 8726
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:57:59 -0600] "GET /index.php?img=gifLogo HTTP/1.1" 200 4549
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:57:59 -0600] "GET /index.php?img=pngWrench HTTP/1.1" 200 741
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:58:41 -0600] "GET /add_vhost.php?lang=english HTTP/1.1" 200 5113
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:58:44 -0600] "POST /add_vhost.php?lang=english HTTP/1.1" 200 5249
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:58:44 -0600] "GET /index.php?img=pngWrench HTTP/1.1" 200 741
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:58:44 -0600] "GET /index.php?img=gifLogo HTTP/1.1" 200 4549
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:58:45 -0600] "POST /add_vhost.php?lang=english HTTP/1.1" 200 4720
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:58:45 -0600] "GET /index.php?img=pngWrench HTTP/1.1" 200 741
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:58:45 -0600] "GET /index.php?img=gifLogo HTTP/1.1" 200 4549
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:58:51 -0600] "POST /add_vhost.php?lang=english HTTP/1.1" 200 3700
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:58:51 -0600] "GET /index.php?img=gifLogo HTTP/1.1" 200 4549
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:59:27 -0600] "\x16\x03\x01\x02" 400 311
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:59:27 -0600] "\x16\x03\x01\x02" 400 311
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:59:27 -0600] "\x16\x03\x01" 400 311
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:59:27 -0600] "\x16\x03\x01" 400 311
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:59:27 -0600] "\x16\x03\x01\x02" 400 311
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:59:27 -0600] "\x16\x03\x01" 400 311
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:59:34 -0600] "\x16\x03\x01\x02" 400 311
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:59:34 -0600] "\x16\x03\x01\x02" 400 311
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:59:34 -0600] "\x16\x03\x01" 400 311
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:59:34 -0600] "\x16\x03\x01" 400 311
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:59:34 -0600] "\x16\x03\x01\x02" 400 311
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:59:34 -0600] "\x16\x03\x01" 400 311
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:59:46 -0600] "\x16\x03\x01\x02" 400 311
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:59:46 -0600] "\x16\x03\x01" 400 311
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:59:46 -0600] "\x16\x03\x01\x02" 400 311
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:59:46 -0600] "\x16\x03\x01" 400 311
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:59:46 -0600] "\x16\x03\x01\x02" 400 311
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:18:59:46 -0600] "\x16\x03\x01" 400 311
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:03:21 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5704
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:03:21 -0600] "GET /index.php?img=gifLogo HTTP/1.1" 200 4549
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:03:21 -0600] "GET /index.php?img=pngPlugin HTTP/1.1" 200 548
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:03:21 -0600] "GET /index.php?img=pngWrench HTTP/1.1" 200 741
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:03:21 -0600] "GET /index.php?img=pngFolder HTTP/1.1" 200 850
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:03:21 -0600] "GET /index.php?img=pngFolderGo HTTP/1.1" 200 694
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:20:49 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5704
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:20:49 -0600] "GET /index.php?img=gifLogo HTTP/1.1" 200 4549
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:20:49 -0600] "GET /index.php?img=pngPlugin HTTP/1.1" 200 548
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:20:49 -0600] "GET /index.php?img=pngWrench HTTP/1.1" 200 741
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:20:49 -0600] "GET /index.php?img=pngFolderGo HTTP/1.1" 200 694
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:20:49 -0600] "GET /index.php?img=pngFolder HTTP/1.1" 200 850
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:20:50 -0600] "GET /add_vhost.php?lang=english HTTP/1.1" 200 5113
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:20:50 -0600] "GET /index.php?img=gifLogo HTTP/1.1" 200 4549
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:20:50 -0600] "GET /index.php?img=pngWrench HTTP/1.1" 200 741
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:21:01 -0600] "POST /add_vhost.php?lang=english HTTP/1.1" 200 3682
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:21:01 -0600] "GET /index.php?img=gifLogo HTTP/1.1" 200 4549
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:22:02 -0600] "\x16\x03\x01\x02" 400 311
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:22:02 -0600] "\x16\x03\x01\x02" 400 311
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:22:02 -0600] "\x16\x03\x01" 400 311
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:22:02 -0600] "\x16\x03\x01" 400 311
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:22:02 -0600] "\x16\x03\x01\x02" 400 311
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:22:02 -0600] "\x16\x03\x01" 400 311
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:22:04 -0600] "\x16\x03\x01\x02" 400 311
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:22:04 -0600] "\x16\x03\x01" 400 311
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:22:56 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5756
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:22:58 -0600] "GET /index.php?img=gifLogo HTTP/1.1" 200 4549
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:22:58 -0600] "GET /index.php?img=pngFolder HTTP/1.1" 200 850
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:22:58 -0600] "GET /index.php?img=pngWrench HTTP/1.1" 200 741
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:22:58 -0600] "GET /index.php?img=pngFolderGo HTTP/1.1" 200 694
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:22:58 -0600] "GET /index.php?img=pngPlugin HTTP/1.1" 200 548
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:22:59 -0600] "GET /add_vhost.php?lang=english HTTP/1.1" 200 5286
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:22:59 -0600] "GET /index.php?img=gifLogo HTTP/1.1" 200 4549
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:22:59 -0600] "GET /index.php?img=pngWrench HTTP/1.1" 200 741
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:23:01 -0600] "POST /add_vhost.php?lang=english HTTP/1.1" 200 5555
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:23:01 -0600] "GET /index.php?img=gifLogo HTTP/1.1" 200 4549
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:23:01 -0600] "GET /index.php?img=pngWrench HTTP/1.1" 200 741
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:23:04 -0600] "POST /add_vhost.php?lang=english HTTP/1.1" 200 4720
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:23:05 -0600] "GET /index.php?img=gifLogo HTTP/1.1" 200 4549
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:23:05 -0600] "GET /index.php?img=pngWrench HTTP/1.1" 200 741
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:23:58 -0600] "POST /add_vhost.php?lang=english HTTP/1.1" 200 3685
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:23:58 -0600] "GET /index.php?img=gifLogo HTTP/1.1" 200 4549
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:27:16 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5674
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:27:16 -0600] "GET /index.php?img=gifLogo HTTP/1.1" 200 4549
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:27:16 -0600] "GET /index.php?img=pngPlugin HTTP/1.1" 200 548
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:27:16 -0600] "GET /index.php?img=pngWrench HTTP/1.1" 200 741
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:27:16 -0600] "GET /index.php?img=pngFolder HTTP/1.1" 200 850
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:27:16 -0600] "GET /index.php?img=pngFolderGo HTTP/1.1" 200 694
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:27:20 -0600] "GET /add_vhost.php?lang=english HTTP/1.1" 200 5102
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:27:20 -0600] "GET /index.php?img=gifLogo HTTP/1.1" 200 4549
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:27:20 -0600] "GET /index.php?img=pngWrench HTTP/1.1" 200 741
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:27:29 -0600] "POST /add_vhost.php?lang=english HTTP/1.1" 200 3700
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:27:30 -0600] "GET /index.php?img=gifLogo HTTP/1.1" 200 4549
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:49:12 -0600] "\x16\x03\x01\x02" 400 311
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:49:12 -0600] "\x16\x03\x01" 400 311
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:49:12 -0600] "\x16\x03\x01\x02" 400 311
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:49:12 -0600] "\x16\x03\x01" 400 311
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:49:12 -0600] "\x16\x03\x01\x02" 400 311
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:49:12 -0600] "\x16\x03\x01\x02" 400 311
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:49:12 -0600] "\x16\x03\x01" 400 311
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:49:12 -0600] "\x16\x03\x01" 400 311
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:49:12 -0600] "\x16\x03\x01\x02" 400 311
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:49:12 -0600] "\x16\x03\x01\x02" 400 311
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:49:12 -0600] "\x16\x03\x01" 400 311
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:49:12 -0600] "\x16\x03\x01" 400 311
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:50:57 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5762
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:50:57 -0600] "GET /index.php?img=gifLogo HTTP/1.1" 200 4549
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:50:57 -0600] "GET /index.php?img=pngPlugin HTTP/1.1" 200 548
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:50:57 -0600] "GET /index.php?img=pngWrench HTTP/1.1" 200 741
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:50:57 -0600] "GET /index.php?img=pngFolder HTTP/1.1" 200 850
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:50:57 -0600] "GET /index.php?img=pngFolderGo HTTP/1.1" 200 694
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:51:06 -0600] "GET /wp-admin HTTP/1.1" 404 293
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:51:20 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/style.css?ver=4.9.1 HTTP/1.1" 200 83036
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:51:20 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:51:20 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:51:20 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/assets/images/header.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 114854
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:51:19 -0600] "GET /mysite/ HTTP/1.1" 200 53420
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:51:20 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-includes/js/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=4.9.1 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:51:20 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/assets/js/skip-link-focus-fix.js?ver=1.0 HTTP/1.1" 200 683
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:51:20 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/assets/js/global.js?ver=1.0 HTTP/1.1" 200 7682
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:51:20 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/assets/js/jquery.scrollTo.js?ver=2.1.2 HTTP/1.1" 200 5836
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:51:20 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-includes/js/wp-embed.min.js?ver=4.9.1 HTTP/1.1" 200 1398
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:51:26 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-admin HTTP/1.1" 301 333
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:51:26 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 -
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:51:27 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8079%2Fmysite%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 2287
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:51:27 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-admin/load-styles.php?c=1&dir=ltr&load%5B%5D=dashicons,buttons,forms,l10n,login&ver=4.9.1 HTTP/1.1" 200 38592
::1 - - [15/Dec/2017:19:51:27 -0600] "GET /mysite/wp-admin/images/wordpress-logo.svg?ver=20131107 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
```

Comment: You have explicit port definitions here, `*:8079`, can I assume that you have an apache directive `Listen 8079`, and can I assume that this is how you are accessing the page? `http://websiteone.dev:8079/`

Comment: And you are accessing the site via `http://websiteone.dev:8079/`? With the port? Have you checked the apache logs for errors? `Connection Refused` means you are sending packets to a socket that is not bound to anything; i.e., apache is not running, apache is not bound to the correct port, or you are not accessing it via the correct port.

Comment: That different error is your _actual_ error, seeing as that one seems to indicate a connection to the webserver. `This site can’t provide a secure connection` means that you have typed `https://` and are trying to connect to an `http` protocol server.

Comment: Matt - thanks for the response.  Yes, My httpd.conf file contains both directives `Listen 0.0.0.0:8079` and `Listen [::0]:8079`.  I have also tried both `http://websiteone.dev` and `http://websiteone.dev:8079/`.  When I add the 8079 port to the url, I receive a different error from Chrome: `This site can’t provide a secure connection websiteone.dev sent an invalid response`

Comment: Please 100% double check the URL. I can reproduce this on my webserver when attempting to access an HTTP protocol server with an HTTPS protocol request. `https://www.google.com:80/` <- this will throw the same error in chrome. If you truly are making an HTTP request, then check your apache web server logs.

Comment: I enter `http://websiteone.dev:8079/`, however after attempting to load the address bar then shows `https://websiteone.dev` while displaying the error message.  I have updated my original post with the Apache error log.

Comment: Sounds like http is working correctly then, and sending a redirect to the user. Check the apache access log, and you might see a 302 response? Either there is some other apache configuration doing this, or your application that is being server from DocumentRoot is causing the redirect.

Comment: I have edited my posted and replaced the error log with access log.  It seems that most lines are in reference to my local host with database `mysite`.  The only reference to a virtual host I see is `GET /add_vhost.php?lang=english HTTP/1.1" 200 ####`

Comment: [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47789610/2310830) specifically the part about `.dev` tLD now being owned by Google and Chrome automatically redirecting `.dev` before looking at your local cache. Try using another browser and see if the problem goes away

Comment: Hey Riggs and Matt, sorry for the delayed response due to the holidays.  I just tried my localhost and virtual hosts on Firefox and IE.  Same result - can log into the front and back end of my localhost but receive a "error establishing a database connection" for the virtual hosts.  Any other suggestions?